# Edit Nginx rewrite rule to work with CodeIgniter and got 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

I tried every answer that give to the same questions in stackoverflow. It give me a progress but still can't find the final solution.

### The problem

I got the `500 Internal Server Error Nginx` error when I post to other controller..

When I examined the /var/log/nginx/error.log, it show the following error;

```
`[error] 17184#0: *8 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php/", client: 58.9.106.64, server: 60daysonline.co, request: "POST /60d/index.php/order/new_order HTTP/1.1", host: "60daysonline.co", referrer: "http://60daysonline.co/60d/"`
```

### Context

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

WebServer: Nginx 1.4.6

Framework: CodeIgniter 2.2.6

Base URL: http://60daysonline.co/

Base CodeIgniter directory: http://60daysonline.co/60d/

### Configuration

File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    server_name www.60daysonline.co;
    return 301 $scheme:/60daysonline.co$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/him_aeng/goo_html/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 60daysonline.co;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$1?$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /home/him_aeng/goo_html_public_html;
    }

    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params

            set $no_cache "";

            if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$) {
                set $no_cache "1";
            }

            if ($no_cache = "1") {
                add_header Set-Cookie "_mcnc=1; Max-Age=2; Path=/";
                add_header X-Microcachable "0";
            }

            if ($http_cookie ~* "_mcnc") {
                        set $no_cache "1";
            }

            fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;

            if ($no_cache = "1") {
                add_header Set-Cookie "_mcnc=1; Max-Age=2; Path=/";
                add_header X-Microcachable "0";
            }

            if ($http_cookie ~* "_mcnc") {
                        set $no_cache "1";
            }

            fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
            fastcgi_cache microcache;
            fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 10m;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
            fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
            fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    }

    location ~*  \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)$ {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

}
```

CodeIgniter's config.php

```
$config['base_url']     = "";
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

### The progress I did so far follow by the instruction in here

I modified the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default until it look like this;

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ [^/]\.(hh|php)(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) { return 404; }
            ...
}
```

and the following is new codeIgniter's config file;

```
$config['base_url']     = "http://60daysonline.co/60d";
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

#### The new problem

I found that when I put the empty string to $config['index_page'], the system will route me to the url that exclude index.php from address such as 
`60daysonline/60day//order/new_order`. It show me the 404 error page.

If I put 'index.php' to $config['index_page'], the url will become `60daysonline/60day/index.php/order/new_order`. And I see the 'root controller page', which is the same page as base url (60daysonline/60d).

It's seem like the system not call function in controller at all (in this case; funciton new_order in Order controller). This is the new problem that I have to continuous find the solution.

Comment: I think try once by putting `base_url` and remove `index.php`

Comment: @VivekSingh when I change config.php as your suggestion, the system send me to `404 page not found` page.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Codeigniter, but you have multiple problems with your `nginx` configuration file.

On line 3, you are missing a `/`, it should be:

```
return 301 $scheme://60daysonline.co$request_uri;
```

In the `try_files` statement of the `location /` block, your default action is `/index.php/$1?$args`, which presents two problems:

1. The value of `$1` is undefined - do you mean `$uri`?
2. You have no location block to process PHP URIs containing path info

Your `location ~ \.(hh|php)$` block only sees URIs which end with `.php`, so URIs which end with `.php/` will cause a redirect loop.

If you need to process PHP URIs containing path info, you will need to change the regex and remove the `try_files` directive within the block. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for details. For example:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) { return 404; }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, avoid path info altogether by changing your default action, and removing the `/$1`. Some examples suggest that `/index.php` is all you need:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for clarity answer. I did exactly modification you're suggested. I make some progress and found the new problem arise.

It is the MVC problem that didn't compatible Nginx's config file.